# Why did Lord Balarama not took a participation at any side of in the Kurukshetra Battle in Mahabharata?

Tags: mahabharata, pandavas, kauravas, kurukshetra, balarama

Lord Krishna fought on the behalf of Pandavas and his army fought on behalf of Kauravas. But why Lord Balarama did not fight on behalf of any side?

Comment: Related: [Why did Balarama favor Duryodhana?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/562/1049)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## why Lord Balarama did not fight on behalf of any side?

The answer is given by Shree Ved Vyasa In Shreemad Bhagavatam . He decided to stay neutral in the war  to avoid an awkward situation .

> श्रुत्वायुद्धोदयमं राम: कुरूणां सह पाण्डवै : |
>  
>   तीर्थाभिषेकव्याजेन मध्यस्थ: प्रययौ किल || [**SB 10.78.17**](http://gitabase.com/eng/SB/10/78/17)||
>
> śrutvā yuddhodyamaḿ rāmaḥ kurūṇāḿ saha pāṇḍavaiḥ
>   tīrthābhiṣeka-vyājena madhya-sthaḥ prayayau kila
>
> Lord Balarama then heard that the Kurus were preparing for war with the Pandavas. Being neutral, He departed on the pretext of going to bathe in holy places.

**Purport** - Both Duryodhana and Yudhishthira were dear to Lord Balarama, and so to avoid an awkward situation He departed. Furthermore, after killing the demon Viduratha, Lord Krishna put aside His weapons, but Lord Balarama still had to kill Romaharshana and Balvala to finish relieving the earth of her burden of demons.